# How to stop excel from changing a range when you drag a formula down?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to normalize a set of columns of data in an excel spreadsheet.

I need to get the values so that the highest value in a column is = 1 and lowest is = to 0, so I've come up with the formula:

`=(A1-MIN(A1:A30))/(MAX(A1:A30)-MIN(A1:A30))`

This seems to work fine, but when I drag down the formula to populate the cells below it, now only does `A1` increase, but `A1:A30` does too.

Is there a way to lock the range while updating just the number I'm interested in?

I've tried putting the Max and min in a different cell and referencing that but it just references the cell under the one that the Max and min are in and I get divide by zero errors because there is nothing there.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A '$' will lock down the reference to an absolute one versus a relative one. You can lock down the column, row or both. Here is a locked down absolute reference for your example.

```
(A1-MIN($A$1:$A$30))/(MAX($A$1:$A$30)-MIN($A$1:$A$30))
```

Comment: Side note: I think it works this way for essentially all modern spreadsheet programs - I know it does for OpenOffice.org Calc and Google Docs' spreadsheet.

Comment: Good answer--but it (and the original question) belong on a different site.

Comment: On a windows machine, you can toggle through the "lock down" methods with the F4 key.